# Using precision as a metric - how to gauge if more TP's

Tags: model-evaluations, binary-classification

So precision is calculated as tp/(tp+fp)

But this doesn't seem to be a good way to assess a model as both of the below would give a result of 1?

Binary Classification

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]   or    [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1]
```

Am I missing something here? Or is there a better metric for binary classification which would limit the amount of false positives while also producing the MOST amount of true positives?

I guess you are going to tell me F1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't make sense without a gold standard, evaluation measures work by comparing predicted labels against true labels.

To answer your question: precision is not sufficient on its own to evaluate a model, it's always used together with recall. And the two are often combined into F-score, indeed.

- Precision only represents the proportion of **correct** positive predictions **among all the positive predictions**.
- Recall only represents the proportion of **correct** positive predictions **among all the gold positive instances**.

> Am I missing something here? Or is there a better metric for binary classification which would limit the amount of false positives while also producing the MOST amount of true positives?

- "limit the amount of false positives" -> precision
- "producing the MOST amount of true positives" -> recall

Technically **accuracy** satisfies both conditions:

$$accuracy=\frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}$$

However accuracy doesn't distinguish between positive and negative instances, and this is often an issue (unless the classes are balanced).